# How to grep only 10 matches in R?

Tags: regex, r

I have a data file where I can grep "you":

```
> dtq_ml_wuv[grep("you", dtq_ml_wuv$rn), "rn"]

"you can take"         "you can tell"         "you can thank"       
"you can try"          "you can turn"         "you can use"         
"you can visit"        "you can work"         "you donet know"      
"you donet need"       "you dont know"        "you get enough"      
"you get see"          "you go back"          "you got keep"        
"you guys can"         "you heard right"      "you just go"         
"you just gotta"       "you just look"        "you just need"       
"you just stay"        "you know better"      "you know else"       
"you know got"         "you know i"           "you know if"         
"you know im"          "you know it"          "you know just"       
"you know many"        "you know means"       "you know one"        
"you know really"      "you know right"       "you like see"
```

How can I get `grep` to **stop** after it found, say 0 to 25 matches?

I tried

```
> dtq_ml_wuv[grep("you{0, 25}", dtq_ml_wuv$rn), "rn"]
```

But it's telling me the expression is invalid because of invalid content of `{}`.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe just `grep("you", dtq_ml_wuv$rn)[1:10]`? or even  `grep("you", dtq_ml_wuv$rn, value = TRUE)[1:10]`

Comment: just returning the first 25 is not enough? `dtq_ml_wuv[grep("you", dtq_ml_wuv$rn), "rn"][1:25]`

Comment: Subsetting `[1:10]` will be terribly inefficient if the vector is a million long and the first ten elements match. You've just done 999,990 regex matches and thrown them away.

Comment: Maybe building the output one iteration at a time and checking for the length of the output every time before grep ?

Comment: @Spacedman That's what I'm saying. Of course I could just return the first ten matches, but then I didn't stop grep from operating over all input. Grep should stop after it matched n, m including zero or max out.

Comment: Partition the search space into chunks and grep over each chunk until you have your desired number.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a chunked version. Tune the chunk size to get the most out of the speed of internal compiled code versus the trade off of searching too many.

```
grepn<-function(pattern,x,n,chunk.size=32) {
  N<-length(x);
  chunk<-1:chunk.size;
  k<-1;
  M<-vector("integer",n+chunk.size);
  while(k < n && chunk[1] <= N) {
    i<-na.omit(grep(pattern,x[chunk]));
    if(length(i)) M[k:(k+length(i)-1)]<-i+chunk[1]-1
    k<-k+length(i)
    chunk<-chunk+chunk.size
  }
  return(M[1:(min(k-1,n))])
}
```

Example with `data` as the character vector in the question

```
grepn("e",data,n=10,chunk.size=16)
[1]  1  2  6  9 10 12 13 15 17 21
```

Comment: What happens when you set `chunk.size` higher than `n`, and we jump past the desired `n`? Or even when `chunk.size` is less than `n`, but the remaining slots in `M` are not enough to accommodate what we find? You probably just need a conditional statement _a la_ `min(k+length(i)-1,N)` **EDIT** I realize that actually you're over-allocating `N`--the memory-efficient way to do this is instead assign `M<-vector("integer",n)` and do what I suggested here

Comment: There's a `na.omit` to handle falling off the end of the data, and a subset in the return statement to trim to `n`. There is potential for waste for any chunk size larger than 1, but the tradeoff of staying in compiled code longer ought to make the most efficient chunk size relatively high. I have not tuned or tested.

Comment: Wasn't reading closely enough; see edit. Anyway, I'm nit-picking--this is going to be the fastest way to solve this, I think, without doing everything in C.

Comment: Gotcha. I changed the allocation to just `n+chunk.size` for the cushion so I don't have a have a `min` each time through and left the rest of the trimming as was.

Comment: If someone wants to bench and tune the default `chunk.size`, edits are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the fastest way around your problem maybe someone comes up with a faster way.

I've created a vector "x" to grep "a" until it reaches 3

```
dput(x)
c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
"p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
```

I used a for loop and if/else conditions

```
out<-NULL
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (grepl("a",x[i])==TRUE){
    out<-append(out,x[i])
  } else {
    next
  }
if (length(out)>2){
  print(out)
  break
} else {
  next
}
}

 out
[1] "a" "a" "a"
```

I have compared it to the subset strategy and it does not differ in time for small vectors. However, when I made my length(x)=25000000

```
ptm<-proc.time();x[grep("a",x)][1:3];proc.time()-ptm
[1] "a" "a" "a"
   user  system elapsed 
   2.25    0.06    2.34
```

vs loop format

```
proc.time()-ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.01    0.03
```